# C# class in array

Tags: c#

this i the program.

```
    using System;
    using System.Linq;

    namespace object_in_array
    {
        class objekt
        {
            public string test = "succes";
        }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object[] test = new object[5];

            objekt yes = new objekt();
            test[0] = yes;

            Console.WriteLine(test[0].test);
        }
    }
    }
```

i want to return the `yes.test` from the array i put the test object in. can someone help pls

Comment: What is the problem or error message?

Comment: You probably want `objekt[] test = new objekt[5];` instead. But that's just a shot in the dark, what is your error?

Comment: Casting perhaps?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want to do, so please edit your question to explain.

Comment: @CorentinPane you might want to post that as answer

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to do something like

```
((objekt)test[0]).test = "yes";
```

Then you are doing it totally wrong and the posted comment by @corentin is correct. You would do

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        objekt[] test = new objekt[5];
        objekt yes = new objekt();
        test[0] = yes;
        Console.WriteLine(test[0].test);
    }
```

Comment: i ment more like i wnated to print succes from the array

Comment: @Arvram610 see edit in answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add `(objekt)` for convert to objekt in your code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace object_in_array
{
    class objekt
    {
        public string test = "succes";
    }
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object[] test = new object[5];

        objekt yes = new objekt();
        test[0] = yes;

        Console.WriteLine(((objekt)test[0]).test);
    }
}
}
```